# Use razor to generate code?

Tags: razor, code-generation

Before I invest a lot of time researching Razor and its applicability, I would like to ask you Razor gurus if one could use Razor to generate C# code? Any issues that you can think of right away?

Comment: comment on "closed as too broad": Is this question really to broad? The real question here is "is it possible to use razor to generate code and if yes how". There is a working example that shows how to generate code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You certainly *could* use Razor to generate C# code, but it's not really designed for non-XML-like languages. You'd have to have a lot of <text> tags.

Comment: Thanks, that's the info I was looking for.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the info about ´<text>´ that helped to create a working demo. (see my answer below)

Comment: Andrew - Razor is 100 times better than any other templating engine I've come across.  Kudos to you!  I most certainly would still rather use it over other gode generators, even w/ <text> tags!

Answer (score 17):

My first try with [razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx).dll version 2.1.4039.23635  was much easier than i expected

Here is a small working demo

The **codegenerator**

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using RazorEngine;

namespace CodeGen3b
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string template = ... see below;
            try
            {
                string generatedCode = Razor.Parse(template, 
                                    new { UserNamespace = "MyOwnNamespace" });
                Debug.WriteLine(generatedCode);

            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The **template** looks like this

```
using System;
namespace @Model.UserNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
              @for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                <text>Debug.WriteLine("hello @i " + @Model.UserNamespace);
</text>}
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `<text>` element that prevents razor from interpreting the `Debug.WriteLine`

The **output** is

```
using System;
namespace MyOwnNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
                Debug.WriteLine("hello 0 " + MyOwnNamespace);
                Debug.WriteLine("hello 1 " + MyOwnNamespace);
                Debug.WriteLine("hello 2 " + MyOwnNamespace);
        }
    }
}
```

It would be nice if Razor would implement `@"..."@` or `@'...'@` as alias for `<text>...</text>` . I added this [razorengine.codeplex-Issue](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/workitem/366) as a request to improve. If you plan to use razor as codegenerator please upvote it at [razorengine.codeplex-Issue](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/workitem/366)

Edit: as @Epitka suggested, we can use `@:` in place of a single line text tag:

```
using System;
namespace @Model.UserNamespace
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
              @for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                @:Debug.WriteLine("hello @i " + @Model.UserNamespace);
              }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: epitka is correct: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx

Comment: @k3b Thanks ! would you please to create a small project of your example and sharing it for download ?

Comment: @Guillaume86: thanks for updating. now i inderstand what epitka meant in his comment :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use razor just like T4 templates to generate any type of text. See this blog post.

http://weblogs.asp.net/mikaelsoderstrom/archive/2010/08/03/use-razor-for-t4-templates.aspx